# How to get documents from CouchDB database in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, couchdb

I'm developing a simple application using CouchDB and Node.js. I have few documents in my database and created a view to retrieve the documents. How can I get the view from CouchDB in my javascript file?

```
 app.get('/find', function(req, res){

var cradle = require('cradle');
var connection = new(cradle.Connection)('http://localhost:5984/', 443);
var db = connection.database('db');

db.view('_design/usersView/users', function (err, response) {
        console.log(response);
});
```

The response says: undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try querying the view like this

```
db.view('usersView/users', function (err, response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

You don't need a `_design/` with cradle (although you need that if you query it with default couchdb api)

Also I think it would be better if you moved the connection and the require statements out of the the controller.

Comment: Then it can possibly be a problem with the view.Can you show post the code for the view and an example of the document that it indexes?

Comment: Nice. Well done! It looks like you had to supply a full url to cradle.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Just sent http get request to couchDB api to retrieve the view with this command:

```
db.get('_design/usersView/_view/users', function (err, doc) {
   res.end(JSON.stringify(doc));
});
```